# Executing a cURL in Android with binary image on Post request

Tags: php, android, opencv, curl, image-processing

I found an API for image recognition in Android i.e. [Pastec](http://pastec.io/) and they gave cURL script for image recognition. It works perfectly there but I want to know how to call this cURL script with Android. The cURL script is

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @/home/test/img/request.jpg http://localhost:4212/index/searcher
```

When I am passing a POST HttpRequest from Android, server is not accepting my file.